remainder term in the calculation of $\gamma_k$ of Aleksandar Ivic's book
In the proof of Theorem 1.3 of Ivic's book on Riemann zeta function, he computes the Laurent coefficients $\gamma_k$ of the zeta function by comparing the $s$ coefficient in the Laurent expansion of $\int_1^\infty t^{-s} dS_r(t)$, where $S_r(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} n^{-1} (\log(x/n))^r$. He basically write the $s$-expansion in two different ways, one of which is
$$S_r(x) = (r+1)^{-1} \log^{r+1} x + \sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}{k} c_k\log^{r-k} x + R_r(x).$$
He seems to rely on the fact that $R_r(x)$ can be written as $\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty a_k s^k$. But I don't see how this is obvious.
